# "You cannot perform this action on PaymentIntents created by Checkout" on client side Stripe

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

I've started to implement ***Stripe*** into my Android app, and that error keeps popping while trying to make payments. I get the ***paymentIntentID*** and the ***clientSecret*** from the backend, where those are generated.

When I pass the ***clientSecret*** to the *paymentSheet*.***presentWithPaymentIntent***, fill out the card info for the [succeding (4242 4242 4242 4242)](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android#:%7E:text=credit%20card%20number-,4242%204242%204242%204242,-with%20any%20expiration) test case, that error shows up.

I've been looking for this error but haven't found much help yet. Did I do my ***paymentSheet*** configuration right?

This is the screenshot of the error:

[image: Error Image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsoTBl.jpg)

This is ***presentPaymentSheet*** function:

```
private fun presentPaymentSheet(paymentIntentClientSecret: String) {
        val configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration("Test")
        paymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent(
            paymentIntentClientSecret,
            configuration
        )
    }
```

Is there a specific case this error occurs? I couldn't find much info on google, since it's not a common problem and 2 of Github issuses with the same error are closed with no explanation or solution whatsoever.

If you need any specific part of the code, let me know, because I have no idea where is the source of this error or how to track this, since it's handled by the library, so, I'm sorry and thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: How are you creating the Payment Intent? Sounds like you're creating a Checkout Session and then using the underlying Payment Intent that Checkout creates.

Comment: Please give some solution for this issue

Comment: What I did was I talked to back-end guys here where I work and we made it so they generate the Payment Intent and send it to me, and not the Checkout Session with the underlying the Payment Intent that it created, just like @JonathanSteele said. So in your case I don't really know how else to help you, other than an advice to talk to the back-end guys, if you are working in a team.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create the payment intent on the back end (not using session/checkout), get the setup intent `client_secret`, and call `confirmCardSetup` with the `client_secret` on the frontend/client-side.

backend:

```js
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe(
  'sk_test_your_secret_key',
  { apiVersion: '2022-11-15' }
);

const main = async () => {
  const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    customer: 'cus_1234',
  });

  console.log(setupIntent.client_secret);
  // should give you something like 'seti_1MP8Y...'
}

main();
```

For testing I copy/pasted the `setupIntent.client_secret`'s value into the following **client side** code:

```js
import { CardElement, Elements, useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe, StripeCardElement } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import React, { ReactElement} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_your-key');

const Form: React.FC = (): ReactElement => {
  const elements = useElements();
  const stripe = useStripe();

  if (!elements) return <></>;

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) return;

    const setupIntentClientSecret = 'seti_1MP8Y...'; // <---------------- Copy and pasted from server side

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(
      setupIntentClientSecret,
      { payment_method: { card: elements.getElement(CardElement) as StripeCardElement } }
    );

    console.log(error);
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <Link to='/service-group/create'>Create Service Group</Link>
      <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <CardElement />
        <button id="submit">
          <span id="button-text">
            Add Payment Method
          </span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </section >
  );
};

const Dashboard: React.FC = (): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}><Form /></Elements>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

This will create the payment method and attach it to the setup intent.

### My use case

I need to make sure I have a valid card on file before the user does something, but I charge them at the beginning of every month. I have a stripe customer created at this point in the application's flow so I provide the customer id when creating the setup intent (though I think that's optional).

Obviously in a real application you'd call a back end API endpoint to create the setup intent and retrieve the client_secret, rather than copying and pasting it.